# Pandas calculate total hours from overlapping time ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df_dict = {
    'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
    'start_time':[
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  1:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  2:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  3:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  4:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  1:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  2:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  3:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  4:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    ],
    'end_time':[
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  2:45PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  3:00PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  4:50PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  4:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  3:45PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  5:00PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  5:50PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2020  6:30PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'),
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)

#    id          start_time            end_time
# 0   1 2020-06-01 13:30:00 2020-06-01 14:45:00
# 1   1 2020-06-01 14:30:00 2020-06-01 15:00:00
# 2   1 2020-06-01 15:30:00 2020-06-01 16:50:00
# 3   1 2020-06-01 16:30:00 2020-06-01 16:30:00
# 4   2 2020-06-01 13:30:00 2020-06-01 15:45:00
# 5   2 2020-06-01 14:30:00 2020-06-01 17:00:00
# 6   2 2020-06-01 15:30:00 2020-06-01 17:50:00
# 7   2 2020-06-01 16:30:00 2020-06-01 18:30:00
```

I want to calculate the total hours for each `id` without double counting the overlapping intervals.

I have the below code, which gives the correct result

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
df.to_sql('df', conn, index=False)

query = '''
SELECT id, SUM(CAST((JulianDay(end_time)-JulianDay(start_time))*24 AS real)) AS total_hours
FROM (
    SELECT s1.id,
           s1.start_time,
           MIN(t1.end_time) AS end_time
    FROM df s1 
    INNER JOIN df t1 ON s1.start_time <= t1.end_time
      AND s1.id = t1.id
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM df t2 
                     WHERE t1.end_time >= t2.start_time AND t1.end_time < t2.end_time AND t2.id = t1.id) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM df s2 
                     WHERE s1.start_time > s2.start_time AND s1.start_time <= s2.end_time AND s2.id = t1.id)
    GROUP BY s1.start_time, s1.id
    ORDER BY s1.id, s1.start_time
    ) x
GROUP BY id
'''

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
print(df)

#    id  total_hours
# 0   1     2.833333
# 1   2     5.000000
```

but I'm wondering if there is a better/more elegant way to approach this, without using SQL.

Comment: *"calculate the total hours for each id"* => `df.groupby('id')` then compute your aggregate with `.apply()` or similar. Another hint is your SQL contains `GROUP BY s1.start_time, s1.id`

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but as I needed the same functionality, let me share my answer.
It is similar to coco18's answer but can handle the case of intervals overlapping and being completely included in other ones.

```py
df = df.sort_values(["id", "start_time", "end_time"])
grouper = df.groupby(by="id")

# The max seen end date for the row and all predecessors.
df["max_seen_end"] = grouper["end_time"].cummax()
# Now the max end date of all former rows
df["max_seen_end"] = grouper["max_seen_end"].shift(1).fillna(pd.Timestamp.min)

# Ensure start/end dates do not overlap with former intervals by moving them
# to the right if needed.
corrected_start = df[["start_time", "max_seen_end"]].max(axis=1)
corrected_end = df[["end_time", "max_seen_end"]].max(axis=1)

df["hours"] = corrected_end - corrected_start
grouper["hours"].sum() / dt.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Result:

```
id
1    2.833333
2    5.000000
Name: hours, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `groupby` function of pandas. The following code will do the work:

```
import numpy as np
df['start_time_tmp']=np.where((df['start_time'] <= df['end_time'].shift(1))&
                              (df['end_time'] >= df['end_time'].shift(1)), df['end_time'].shift(1), df['start_time'])
df['diff'] = df['end_time']-df['start_time_tmp']
df.groupby(by='id')['diff'].sum().dt.total_seconds()/60/60
```

Output is:

```
id
1    2.833333
2    5.000000
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```

I hope, the code is self explanatory. If you need some help about the `groupby` function you can look the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what your SQL code does is to remove overlapping intervals. You should do the same here. My suggestion is the following:

```
def remove_overlap_intervals(intervals):
    sorted = sorted(intervals, key=lambda tup: tup[0])
    merged = []

    for a in sorted:
        if not merged:
            merged.append(a)
        else:
            b = merged[-1]
            if a[0] <= b[1]:
                upper_bound = max(b[1], a[1])
                merged[-1] = (b[0], upper_bound) 
            else:
                merged.append(a)
    return merged
```

Then do exactly what you would do if the intevals weren't overlapping:

```
df['time'] = df[['start_time', 'end_time']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
Grouped = df.groupby(['id'])['time'].apply(list)
Grouped_no_overlap = Grouped.apply(remove_overlap_intervals)

Grouped = Grouped_no_overlap.apply(lambda x: sum([(y[1]-y[0]).seconds for y in x]))/3600
```

which gives:

```
id
1    2.833333
2    5.000000
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the time resolution of your datetimes is limited to **minutes**.

So one of possible solutions is:

- for each row in a group (by *id*), generate *date_range* object with *minute* frequency,
  excluding the right edge of the respective range,
- concatenate these ranges,
- compute the sum of unique values (for now we have the number of minutes),
- divide it by 60, getting the number of hours.

The code to do it is:

1. Define *getRng* function to generate the *date_range* object from the current *row*:

   ```
   def getRng(row):
       return pd.date_range(row.start_time, row.end_time, freq='min', closed='left')
   ```
2. Define *getHrs* function to compute the number of hours for the current group:

   ```
   def getHrs(grp):
       return np.unique(np.hstack(grp.apply(getRng, axis=1))).size / 60
   ```

   I deliberately chose *Numpy* functions, as they are known to operate
   faster than those of *Pandas*.
3. Apply the above function to each group (by *id*) and convert the result
   to a DataFrame:

   ```
   result = df.groupby('id').apply(getHrs).rename('total_hours').reset_index()
   ```

For your data sample, the result is:

```
   id  total_hours
0   1     2.833333
1   2     5.000000
```

​
I think, this solution is shorter (just 5 lines of code), more readable
than your SQL and more *pandasonic*.